# declaration is incompatible with "void std::Student::setInfo(char *s, char *p)" (declared at line 10 of "Student.h")

Tags: c++, c++11, memory, dynamic, allocation

I have the following files: Student.h and Student.cpp

```
// Student.h
namespace std
{
    class Student
    {
    private:
        char m_studentId[10];
        char m_programCode[4];
    public:
        void getInfo(void) const;
        void setInfo(const char *s, const char *p);
    };
}
```

Student.cpp

```
// Student.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include "Student.h"

using namespace std;

namespace std
{
    void Student::getInfo(void) const
    {
        cout << "Student ID: " << m_studentId << endl;
        cout << "Program: " << m_programCode << endl;
    }

    void Student::setInfo(const char *s,const char *p)
    {
        strcpy(m_studentId, s);
        strcpy(m_programCode, p);
    }
}
```

The code actually compiles and runs quite successfully. However, Visual Studio is giving me the error:

declaration is incompatible with "void std::Student::setInfo(char *s, char *p)" (declared at line 10 of "Student.h").

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in general you should not place you classes in the `std` namespace. Why did you do this?

Comment: Could not reproduce. Your code conflicts with the signature shown in the error message.

Comment: replace `namespace std` with `namespace someOtherName`

Comment: How can it compile and run successfully if it gives you an error?

Comment: Are you talking about a red squiggly underline that shows a "stray" error? It is not uncommon for it to go away on full recompile.

Comment: OT: it's C++. Use std:.string, Don't use char arrays and strcpy.

Comment: `namespace std { ... }` results in undefined behaviour.  Fix this and re-ask as reasoning about UB is a waste of time. See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std

Comment: user463035818 Yes, I knew this. However, I'm just trying to experiment what gives out an error and what doesn't.

dasblinkenlight Yes, the red squiggly line that runs on intellisense while using VS Code.

manni66 I've also thought about that, however, the school hasn't taught us to use std::string. It makes sense however. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: The error message says that the parameters are `char*` while the code shows `const char*`.

Comment: Intellisense will have false positives.

Comment: How does it compile and "run successfully" without `main()`?  If we are to help you, we need a [MCVE]

Comment: Never put anything into `namespace std` unless you have a very good reason to, and can prove that it cannot possibly conflict with anything in the standard library, now and forever.